# Copy left navigation from one subsite to other subsite

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

I want to copy the quick launch from one subsite to other subsite using pnp powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the subsites are under the same parent site, here is a sample script for your reference:

```
#Connect to SPO site using PnP PowerShell
$SiteUrl = "https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com/sites/<ParentSite>"
$Username = "<Admin>"
$Password = "<Password>"
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $UserName, $(convertto-securestring $Password -asplaintext -force)
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl -Credential $cred

#Parameters
$SourceSub = "/sites/Team/sub1"
$TargetSub = "/sites/Team/sub2"

#Add Navigation Links
$n = Get-PnPNavigationNode -Web $SourceSub -Location QuickLaunch
Foreach($_ in $n){
    Add-PnPNavigationNode -Web $TargetSub -Title $_.Title -Url $_.Url -Location QuickLaunch
}
```

Remember to use the **relative URLs** in the script.

It might return several errors since links like “Notebook” and “Site Contents” cannot be duplicated.

References: [Get-PnPNavigationNode.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpnavigationnode?view=sharepoint-ps) / [Add-PnPNavigationNode.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpnavigationnode?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: Thanks!! it is really works well

Comment: Can i get the script for read the quick launch from sharepoint 2013 and update it back with sharepoint online site

Comment: @Liz Glad it helps. 
For the second question: You can first use “Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl” to connect to SharePoint Server 2013, run the command “$n = Get-PnPNavigationNode -Web $SourceSub -Location QuickLaunch”. Then run the Connect-PnPOnline command again to connect to SharePoint Online, and run the following cmdlet “Foreach($_ in $n){Add-PnPNavigationNode -Web $TargetSub -Title $_.Title -Url $_.Url -Location QuickLaunch}”. It will work per my test, but it cannot read the sub links from the source site, only the first-level ones will get returned.